# Not getting data inside WebView from react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview, expo

Added Webview in react Native which render s a html

On load of webview i am taking a webview ref and calling a postmessage message function and passing the data.

In webview html script tag, i have added 'message' event listener to catch the data from webview, its never coming.

React Native webview code:

```
this.refs.webview.postMessage(“Hello There”);
<WebView
                ref="webview"
                style={styles.WebViewContainer}
                javaScriptEnabled={true}
                domStorageEnabled={true}
                source={require('../IntegrationTemplates/template_responsive.html')}
                scalesPageToFit={true}
            />
```

in HTML head:

```
    <script>

    window.addEventListener('message', function(data) {
//data not coming here
                alert("message" + data.data);
            }, false)
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use document instead of window:

```
<script>

document.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
   console.log("Received post message", event);
}, false);

</script>
```